# How do you sort price category with pipes using Angular 2?

Tags: angular

Below is my HTML file to sort price category but my Pipe does not
quite work. Two objects in my products model are priceCategory: string, Price:  Number --> and more: color, brand, type, memory, etc...

(3)Items: (1.) Price: $225,   priceCategory = '$200-300',
           (2.) Price: $75,  priceCategory = '$50-100',
           (3.) Price: $1000,  priceCategory = '$1000-1100

```
<div [ngClass]="displayPriceCategory"> 
  <ul *ngFor="let priceCategory of priceCategories | orderby: ['fieldName']; let i = index">
   <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value={{priceCategory.selected}} 
    [ngModel]="priceCategory.selected" (change)="onPriceCategory($event, i)">
    {{ priceCategory.fieldName}}({{priceCategory.getCount()}})
   </div>
 </div>
```

The results are:

```
 $1000-111 (1)
 $200-300 (1)
 $50-100 (1)
```

It sorts it alphabetically but not in terms of string length.  The pipe I am using works with the Brand Category(Apple, Google, Samsung), Color(black, green, white) - using the same code for HTML, by replacing PriceCategory - BrandCategory, ColorCategory, etc. I copied the Pipe Code from Stack Overflow since I don't know so much about pipes.

Comment: We're not going to be able to reasonably answer this question until you produce your entire component in at least a minimum example fashion.

Comment: Bubble sort works with price(ASC, DESC), title(ASC,DESC), and
Brand(ASC, DESC).

Comment: My app is just any other shopping cart. It sorts the category: $50-100 comes first before $1000-1100. It is just plain string sorting. NOTE: Product component sorts the price category and the search products. This is my solution for my app for now while learning Angular 2 pipes.

Answer (score 0):

### How am I using bubble sort to sort price category in order?

I created a class: SearchField

```
export class SearchField {
    fieldName: string;  //Apple, Samsung, Memory, color, et..
    products: Product[];  //the products in the field; 
    selected: boolean;    //if this field is selected, shows the products in the product list.
    constructor(fieldName: string) {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
        this.products = [];
        this.selected = false;
    }
    addProduct(product: Product) {
        this.products.push(product);
    }
    getProducts() {
        return this.products;
    }
    // $0-100 (3) : tells shopper there are 3 products that belong to $0-100. If this field is selected, 3 items appear in product list. 
    getCount() {
        return this.products.length;
    }
}
```

To get a better understanding of my app: The Filter results are displayed on the left while product search/found takes most of the space on the center. Products varies: toys, video-games, shoes, etc..

```
FILTER RESULTS              Iphone, $700, white, AT&T, 2GB, etc.
Title: Asc, Desc            Pixel, $700, white, Verizon, 2GB, etc..
Price: Asc, Desc            Iphone SE, $550, black, AT&T, 1GB, etc..
Price
  $500-600(1)
  $700-800(2)
Brand
  Apple(2)
  Google(1)
```

Before I implemented bubble sort, I stored all the search items in an array in my service. For price category: priceCategories: SearchField[];

```
getPriceCategoryQueries() {
    for(let i=0; i<priceCategories.length; i++){
        var searchProduct = this.searchProducts[i];
        if(count == 0) {
            let aPriceCategory = new SearchField(searchProduct.priceCategory);
            aPriceCategory.addProduct(searchProduct);
            this.priceCategories.push(aPriceCategory);
            count = 1;
        }else addProductToPriceCategory(searchProduct);
     } this.sortPriceCategory();
}
//Here is the bubble sort to to sort priceCategory in order
//All I am doing is comparing the 1st item in that category to the next.
sortPriceCategory(){
    var temp: any;
    let swapped = true;
    let j = 0;
    for(let i=0; i<this.priceCategories.length; i++){
        if(this.priceCategories[i].product(0).price > this.priceCategories[i+1].products[0].price) {
            temp = priceCategories[i];
            this.priceCategories[i] = this.priceCategories[i+1];
            this.priceCategories[i+1] = temp;
            swapped = true;
         }
     }
}
```

Conclusion: Pipes are great. They have the same code for brandCategory, Color, etc, but the pipe I am using does not work for priceCategory, and sizeCategory: size 2-5 comes before size 10 - 15.
That is the reason why I am using bubble sort. If I help you in anyway, please vote for my "OWN ANSWER" for my application.