# Angular concept: using classes with async

Tags: angular, rest, asynchronous

I come from the old school desktop programming world, and I don't get how classes fit into Angular apps with async backends. Furthermore, I've looked at some projects, and I don't see a lot of classes. I like Angular, I'm just confused about this point.

Let's say I store information about people in my DB and my Angular app interacts with that backend through a REST API. I understand using a person interface because I can nicely format my data when sending and receiving, but I'm not clear on the value of a person class. To read and write to my people DB, I have an Angular service that returns observables so I can be sure when the calls have returned. So I wrap every operation that goes through the person service in that code.

Now, if I create a person class and add an 'add' or 'delete' method to that class, I still have to wrap my call to the service in the subscribe or map (or whatever) to be sure the call has finished. The actual call to the service is a minor part of that code, so it doesn't seem like I'm saving code or encapsulating anything. Why would I want a person class?

Comment: I place all my CRUD operations in a service. In my whole app, I only created methods for 1 class. I need this class to keep track of the quantity of an object.

Comment: So I'm not crazy then? Thanks for the comment

Comment: Below is the only class I used in my app:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41387316/how-do-you-sort-price-category-with-pipes-using-angular-2/41475768?s=1|51.9641#41475768

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have all the async functionality wrapped in a Class.

It would look something like this, with the service being injected into the class. (You can call fetch or a similar method without injecting a service but again, that would be a lot of duplication of code.)

```
Class Person {
    id: string
    name: string, 
    getName(httpService) {
        httpService.get(/persons/id).subscribe()
            .then((value) => this.name = value.name)
    }
}
```

But It's usually not how things are done. It's much cleaner to have common services that handle the async requests.

Classes are still useful for,

- Non async tasks(ex- getter for a full name)
- As you mentioned, having interfaces for retrieving and sending data is really helpful especially with Typescript(and we are using Typewriter which does the class generation automatically from C# code which really helps in keeping models in sync with the backend.)
- Creating exportable modules that is used by Angular.